# Issue with Python Spinner Display - Output Only Appears at the end of program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to implement a Python spinner using the following code:

```py
from time import sleep

for _ in range(10):
    for i in '|/-\\':
        print(i, end='')
        sleep(2)
        print('\b', end='')
```

The expectation is that the code should print a character, wait for 2 seconds, delete it, and then repeat the process. However, when I run this code, it produces a blank line and only displays the output once the loop has completed or is manually interrupted.

I've tested it on both cmd and PowerShell, and the behavior persists. Is there something I'm missing in the code or an issue with the environment? Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: print output normally buffers internally.  you will probably have to redirect directly to stdout to get the data to flush after every write.

Comment: you can try also passing the keyword argument `flush=True` to print as you do with `end=''`

Comment: Thanks didn't know about that
it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from time import sleep
import sys

for _ in range(10):
    for i in '|/-\\':
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sleep(2)
        print('\b', end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `print(i, end='\r')` and remove `print('\b', end='')`